# Line break between inline elements

Tags: css

In the below code, I need to place `a` tag in new line and maintain the center alignment. I cannot change the html.  `display:block` makes the more clickable area outside the text.

Below is the screenshot for required result

[image]

```css
div{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
a{
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="">This is link in new line</a> Cumque mollitia repellat soluta voluptates molestias veniam reiciendis.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nq7ow9eq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display:block` to `a`

```css
div{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
a{
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="">This is link in new line</a> Cumque mollitia repellat soluta voluptates molestias veniam reiciendis.
</div>
```

To remove the extra clickable area

```css
div {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
a {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
}
a:after {
  content: "\a";
 white-space: pre;
}
a:before {
  content: "\a";
 white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="">This is link in new line</a> Cumque mollitia repellat soluta voluptates molestias veniam reiciendis.
</div>
```

Comment: how to remove the extra clickable area on left and right?

Comment: @afelixj Edited check it now

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/z4bef695/).

Simply add `display: table; margin: 0 auto;` to the `a` tag.

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="">This is link in new line</a> Cumque mollitia repellat soluta voluptates molestias veniam reiciendis.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}

a {
  color: red;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That precisely is what block display is for:

```css
div{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
a{
  color: red;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="">This is link in new line</a> Cumque mollitia repellat soluta voluptates molestias veniam reiciendis.
</div>
```

Comment: how to remove the extra clickable area on left and right?

Answer (score 0):

yes display:block; works fine in this situation,
but it matches ALL `<a>` tags on web page.
A better solution is using  selectors and class attribute or id to prevent display new line as block element for `<a>` (normally this line by default).

for example

```
div.div_with_a_newline_by_css > a
{
  color: red;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

or direct in tag a identified by class

```
a.tag_and_newlines{
  color: red;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

BTW
This is not an optimal solution at all but it works,
please remember

---

***tag a is inline by default in box model :)***